# Is there any reason Google Cloud Messaging won't work on a 3rd party server host, like Openshift?

Tags: openshift, google-cloud-messaging

Planning to build backend in Java on OpenShift, and need to use GCM for messaging to device. Is there any reason that this would be a bad idea compared with using AppEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend - called **3rd-party Application Server** in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#server) - does not have to be running on Google App Engine.

I run the server on GlassFish v3 on a Ubuntu Linux system and communication with GCM works well. Testing can be done on a local installation of GlassFish with the Android emulator - as long as the local machine can access the Internet (for HTTP requests to GCM).